# Form validation using java script fail in IE-7 but working fine in from IE-8 onwards

Tags: javascript

I have a user registration page,in which the mandatory fields are validated using java script.it works fine in all browsers and IE-8,9 but it's not working in IE-7.

The issue arises when validating password match.Below is requirement for pass word match

1. Pass word contain at least one number
2. Letters not repeat
3. it contain special characters.
4. Pass word must contain at least 6 letters.

Below is my code for validating the password match

```
function PasswordLenghtVal(pass)  // validating pass word length  
{
    if(/\d/.test(pass) && pass.length >= 6)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function FirstNonRepeatedChar(str)   //validating letters repeating or not  
{
    var i,j,repeated = 0;
    var len = str.length;

    for( i = 0; i < len-1; i++ )
    {
        repeated = 0;
        if(str[i] == str[i+1] ) // checking for existing or not 
        {

        repeated = 1;
        break;
        }
    }
        if( repeated == 0 )  
            return true;       
        else
        return false;
}
```

This is code i have used for pass word match. Only problem in IE-7

Comment: You may want to select an answer. It'll mark the question as solved so that people can use it for reference, and you get a bit of reputation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` getter syntax for `string` is not available in IE7.

```
if(str[i] == str[i + 1]) // checking for existing or not
```

Change it with

```
if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1))
```

And you can check it with regular expression:

```
function FirstNonRepeatedChar(str) {
  return !/(.)\1/.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. First, you want to test each individual component in IE8 and IE7. Then, make it so that if its IE7 it uses something that works (Apparently the problem is `str[]` but as I do not use JavaScript very much I can't tell myself.) Just have a statement that redirects to a working piece of code if it's IE7 or below, and otherwise it goes to what you have.

My idea (Not real code, just to demonstrate what I mean - As I said I don't sue JS much):

```
if(browser = "IE7") {
    //Code that works in IE7
} else {
    //Code that works in everything else
}
```